# Security issue with serving media files

Tags: django

## Description

I have a site where everyone can upload files. It's like an sharehoster, but with the exeption that you shouldn't get the URL to your uploaded file and also have no other possibility to access the files.

The upload works nicely, but i would like to know if it's offending some security policies in production. Especially because of my lack with this MEDIA_URL.

## The Code:

### settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/var/www/project/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

### models.py

```
class File(models.Model):
    myfile = models.FileField(upload_to='%Y/%m/%d/%H/%M/%S')
```

### forms.py

```
class FileForm(forms.Form):
    myfile = forms.FileField()
```

### urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.upload),
)
```

### views.py

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = File(myfile = request.FILES['myfile'])
            newdoc.save()

            return render(request, 'project/index.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = FileForm()

        return render(request, 'project/index.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 1):

What about checking the size of the files? An attacker might try to upload some huge files until the server's disk is full.

Comment: I will add that based on the uploaders ip-address (limit per hour). Thanks :)